# How to fix Ubuntu installation error with wubi?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 inside windows installer in my system, partition E.
I just cut Ubuntu and paste into another location and after that, Ubuntu is not working. Whenever I try to install, it shows following error message:

**An error occurred: Error executing command**

> > command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe/set
> >     {ccdaaf92-e976-11e1-a206-dde85cb781c2}device partition=E:
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=An error has occured setting the element data.
> >     The request is not supported.
> >
> > stdout=
> >
> > For more information, please see the log file:
> >     c:/users\advent~1\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev272.log

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the answer in itself! you shouldn't do that. I you want to change the location, test this:

1. Install another instance of Ubuntu where you like.
2. Replace new Ubuntu files with old ones.

I haven't tested this myself.